# Persistent RMI client connectivity issue

Tags: jakarta-ee

I completely new to RMI technology but I've come to see it as a very important middle-ware architecture to building real world distributed apps. Challenges I've faced in trying to connect the client program to the server program brought me to this site. A code i did earlier kept giving me java.rmi.ConnectException...unable to host 127.0.0.1. Actually I intend to run these programs locally first. So all the programs are on the same computer and folder. My Os is windows 7.

i followed the directives/advice i got from other forums but the error persisted. The directive i followed include
1 referencing the rmi.server.hostname property when running the server program

2 editing the hosts folder under \etc folder

The same exception persisted. The RMI program is a basic "Hello world" printed through a sayHello() method invoked from the client. Now some one posted the code shown below to me. I tried connecting from the client program passing the hostname, port number and a string text as runtime parameters, the exception that persisted this time is java.rmi.UnknownHostException..I seriously want to resolve all this issue to try bigger projects.I appreciate if someone can give a clue to it all.

Olakunle Oladipo Oni

```
     import java.rmi.*;

     public interface ReceiveMessageInterface extends Remote
     {


    void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException;

 }
```

RmiServer.java

```
   import java.rmi.*;

    import java.rmi.registry.*;

    import java.rmi.server.*;

    import java.net.*;



   public class RmiServer extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject

   implements ReceiveMessageInterface

    {

       int thisPort;

       String   thisAddress;

       Registry registry;    // rmi registry for lookup the remote objects.



    // This method is called from the remote client by the RMI.

    // This is the implementation of the �gReceiveMessageInterface�h.

       public void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException
       {

        System.out.println(x);

       }
       public RmiServer() throws RemoteException
       {

         try
         {

            // get the address of this host.

            thisAddress= (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {

            throw new RemoteException("can't get inet address.");

         }
         thisPort=1099;  // this port(registry�fs port)

         System.out.println("this address="+thisAddress+",port="+thisPort);

        try
        {

        // create the registry and bind the name and object.
         registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( thisPort );
         registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        }
        catch(RemoteException e)
        {

        throw e;

        }

    }
        static public void main(String args[])
        {

         try
         {
          RmiServer s=new RmiServer();
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {

           e.printStackTrace();

           System.exit(1);

         }

     }

}
```

RmiClient.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RmiClient
{
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
       ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
       Registry registry;
       String serverAddress=args[0];
       String serverPort=args[1];
       String text=args[2];
       System.out.println("sending "+text+" to "+serverAddress+":"+serverPort);
       try
       {
       // get the �gregistry�h
         registry=LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress,
           (new Integer(serverPort)).intValue()
         );
       // look up the remote object
         jrmiServer=
          (ReceiveMessageInterface)(registry.lookup("rmiServer"));
       // call the remote method
       rmiServer.receiveMessage(text);
   }
   catch(RemoteException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(NotBoundException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


   }
}
```